# Use Ruby Class In A Different Directory

Tags: ruby, jruby, load-path

I have written a few ruby classes.  However, when trying to access one from another directory I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Main::AppVersion
```

This is what the directory structure looks like:

```
home --> a --> app_version.rb
home --> b --> c --> lib --> main.rb (and other classes)
```

Everything within "lib" can see each other.  However, when trying to access app_version, it fails.  I added the path to app version (home/a) to the $LOAD_PATH.  So it should be available from there.  I have also tried "requiring" my other class, but when I do that I get the following error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- AppVersion
```

Any idea on what I could be doing wrong here would be highly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try using require_relative:

```
require_relative '../../../a/app_version'
```

Comment: I tried that as well.  But your post did help answer my question.  I was doing require 'AppVersion' not 'app_version'.  Fixed now, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. require statements look for file names instead of class. Typically you exclude the '.rb'

Answer (score 0):

You error is:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- AppVersion
```

So `require` is looking for a file `AppVersion.rb`. And you said the file name is `app_version.rb`. Try to load it with:

```
require 'app_version'
```

after setting up the `$LOAD_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define Main::AppVersion class it's supposed to reside in **main** folder (i.e. main/app_version.rb)

So it doesn't depend on $LOAD_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to require the file.

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- AppVersion
```

Do you `require "app_version"` ? Or require "AppVersion"? (first one is correct, and consider to `require_relative`)

Another option is to run ruby and give the include path like

```
ruby -Ia -Ib/c/lib b/c/lib/main.rb
```

.